# Test for existence of field in django class

Tags: python, django

Given a django class and a field name how can you test to see whether the class has a field with the given name?

The field name is a string in this case.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

`field_name_exists = field_name in ModelName._meta.get_all_field_names()`